# Local python version not changing after installing pyenv-win

Tags: python, windows, pyenv

I've recently installed `pyenv-win` on my Windows machine using the `pip` [documentation](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win#installation) as I already had Python 3.8.5 installed on my machine. Having used `pyenv` to set the global version to 3.7.6:

- Running `pyenv which python` returns `C:\Users\Haydn\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.6\python.exe` as expected
- However, running `python -V` returns `Python 3.8.5`
- and `pip -V` returns `pip 20.2.2 from C:\Users\Haydn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)`

Installing other packages such as `pipenv` does so in the Python 3.8 folder and fails, as do projects requiring Python 3.7. I'm trying to work out what I could have done wrong or might not be working so that the `pyenv` 3.7 version is used over the system 3.8.

---

Everything seems to have progressed fine during installation:

- `pyenv --version` returns `pyenv 2.64.3`
- Environment variable `PYENV` is set to `C:\Users\Haydn\.pyenv\pyenv-win\`
- `C:\Users\Haydn\.pyenv\pyenv-win\bin` & `C:\Users\Haydn\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims` are added to the `Path` environment variable.

I don't know much about environment variables, but my suspicion is towards the fact that installing Python 3.7 using `pyenv` has not added anything to my `Path` variable (see screenshot), so when I call `python` it's just moving into the 3.8 folder as expected. I feel like `pyenv` should have added something here but that may not be how the package works and something else could very well be the cause.

[screenshot of Path variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzp9k.png)

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 5):

Python installed path that was set in environment variables PATH seems override the pyenv-win configuration. If any Python installation directory was previously set in PATH try deleting it as pointed out in this: [pyenv global interpreter not working on windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64138572/pyenv-global-interpreter-not-working-on-windows10)

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to further @nhieckqo answer but don't have the required rep yet, so...

After deleting the paths entries from a system install of python3.9 via Windows Store,
I also had to disable ALL aliases for python3.9 (not just App Installer as the pyenv github suggests).

See "NOTE" here:
https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/tree/057ba9e97bc5f217ddcffc01768174495c78859a#finish-the-installation

Answer (score 2):

`pyenv rehash` seem to do the trick for me.
I've had similar issue where Path did not get pointed at proper python installation. Rehashing fixed the issue.

There was also other issue reported on pyenv-win github: https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/issues/67
But that seem to be resolved already - rehash was actually an idea from there.