# pyenv global interpreter not working on windows10

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, pyenv

I have just installed pyenv following the installation guide [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win), things goes smoothly, but i could not make the pyenv global python as the global interpreter

I have `rehashed` after installation using `pyenv rehash`

```
PS D:\> pyenv versions
  3.5.1
  3.6.2
  3.7.7
* 3.8.2 (set by C:\Users\xxx\.pyenv\pyenv-win\version)
```

results

```
> python --version
> 3.8.4

# expected
> 3.8.2
```

therefore, I am not able to use `virtualenv` with the `pyenv` installed python interpreter

```
virtualenv py382-djangodev --python=3.8.2
The path 3.8.2 (from --python=3.8.2) does not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In windows NT, the `PATH` variable is a combined result of the system and user variables:

> The Path is constructed from the system path, which can be viewed in
> the System Environment Variables field in the System dialog box. The
> User path is appended to the system path

Shims `PATH` are defined in the user variables, so make sure your host python interpreter path is not defined in your system path

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue which I finally solved:

1 - Uninstall Python (your current version when you type the command python -V)

2 - Install pyenv-win and add it to the PATH (here are some optional steps to install it via chocolatey, which adds it directly to the PATH)

2.2 - Install chocolatey

2.3 - In an administrator powershell run: `choco install pyenv-win`

3 - Start menu (windows key) -> Manage application execution aliases -> disable aliases related to python
[image: here it's in french but it should be similar]

4 - install the desired python version via pyenv: `pyenv install DESIRED VERSION NUMBER`

5- run `pyenv rehash`

6 - set it as global `pyenv global DESIRED VERSION NUMBER`

7 - you sould see the desired version by running the command `python -V`

Comment: Step 3 was the solution, otherwise Store was getting launched

Answer (score 1):

Deinstalling everything connected to python (except pyenv) and using pyenv only worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot Pyenv and python conflict on Windows (also for other OS; simply replace PS command `Get-Command python` with bash command `which python` that identifies location of Python executable.), follow these steps to ensure Python is running from intended source (we need pyenv shims like in last step 5):

1. Determine current Python executable source:

   - Run `Get-Command python` or `(Get-Command python).Source` in PowerShell.
   - If source points to directory like `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310` or in my case `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`.
2. Remove conflicting Python source directory from environment variables:

   - Press `Win + S` to search.
   - Type `edit environment variables for your account`.
   - Open and click `Environment Variables...` button.
   - Locate `Path` variable for both user and system, then click edit button.
   - Find directory of Python source identified in step 1 (`Get-Command python`, source).
   - Delete this variable from both user and system environment variables.
3. Verify Python command results in an error:

   - Open a new cmd and type `python`. It should return an error since conflicting Python source dir has been removed and there is not any python executable. If python is executed check step 1 (`Get-Command python`, source) and Environment Variables on your system.
4. Set up environment variables for Pyenv:

   - Add the following directories to your `Path` environment variable (replace `your_username` with your actual OS username):

     - `C:\Users\your_username\.pyenv\pyenv-win\bin`
     - `C:\Users\your_username\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims`
5. Reopen cmd and check if Pyenv is properly set up:

   - Type `python` and verify that Pyenv (shims dir) is being used by repeating step 1 (`Get-Command python`, source). The result should show the Pyenv paths like:

     ```
     ➜ ~  Get-Command python
     Source   
     C:\Users\your_username\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims\...
     ```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all python versions (like 3.8.4 in your case) not installed using pyenv. I did using Control Panel in Windows. Then what you set as the global version using pyenv will be the true global version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).