# Installation in virtualenv is attempting to run the global Python binary and failing

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Right now I'm trying to install python (3.10) and all further installations on my new pc (windows 10) and so far everything is set up:

- Python installed
- Windows paths for "Python" & "Python\Scrips"

I am able to call the python and pip version and also install some packages. But after installing `virtualenv` and creating one the - at the moment - unfixable error appears: I am unable to install packages into the pip-path of the virtualenviroment itself. Whenever I'm trying to run any pip-command I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\ExampleUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe "C:\folder\env\Scripts\pip.exe" '
```

As you can see, it's always refering to the original python-path, but on the other hand it's refering to the pip-path of the virtualenv!? Don't know if it's helpful, but when typing in `where python` and `where pip` the paths inside the venv are the first one listed. I've also watched out for no blank spaces in my path...

Unfortunately no explanation out there could help me until now and I never faced this problem on my old machine - mostly the same, except some older version of `python`, `pip` and `virtualenv`.

Does anyone else has an idea what I am missing?

Comment: What exact sequence of commands, including the one to create the virtualenv, leads to that error?

Comment: 1. "virtualenv env", 2. ".\Scripts\Activate.ps1", 3. "pip install something..."

Comment: Is the actual "ExampleUser" folder name has a space? If so see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71039131) solves your problem. I think `virtualenv` does run `venv` in the background.

Comment: No, there is no space in the entire path! Many mentioned that this might cause this problem, so I especially watched out for it.

Comment: @finethen Please [edit] your question to include those steps.

Comment: Please show in your question, the actual steps / commands that you have run; and when sensible the full (error) outputs. How did you install virtualenv? How did you create the virtual environments? And so on. Do this the best you can, the most detailed you can so that we can try and reproduce your issue.

Comment: @finethen What happens if you do `python -m pip install something`?

Comment: Are you using the basic Python installation or Anaconda?  Because the virtual environment steps are a little different.  I just setup a virtual environment in Anaconda and it works great with different libraries backing the math libraries.  Because I'm compiling modules for import, they HAVE to be separated... All on Windows 10 so I may be able to help.  If it's `venv` backed I have 2 PCs with environments setup already, and the initial steps can be a bit painful...

Comment: Been using the python installation but will give anaconda a try.

Comment: had a similar issue, try to install pyenv like I described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67986712/14096211

Answer (score 1):

1. downloading Python 3 at the official website and installing it via express installation
2. Copy & Paste the standalone python into the `/python` folder and overwriting the python version
3. running python -m pip install --upgrade pip in cmd

Now pip and python 3 are installed in their latest version.

It's work for me

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use `venv` to create your virtual environment, instead of `virtualenv` (given that `venv` is the [recommended way to create virtual environments](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#installing-virtualenv) for Python 3.3, and newer)?

If using `venv` is an option, [this procedure](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment) may give you some idea on how to do it.

I have not done any Python development on Windows, but I think the basics would be:

```
python3 -m venv your-env-directory
your-env-directory\Scripts\activate.bat
```

If using `venv` is not an option, maybe you can try specifying the [`-v` flag](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/cli_interface.html) when running your `virtualenv` command to increase verbosity so you can further troubleshoot what's going on.

Comment: Already tried using venv instead of virtualenv - unfortunately no change here!

Comment: Can you list the commands you used to set it up your virtual environment using `venv`? I assume you activated the virtual environment (i.e. ran the activate script) after creating it, right?

Answer (score 0):

try upgrade pip version `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*[ Sorry if this answer turns out to be more of a comment than an answer. I only have 21 reputation, so I cannot comment ]*

When trying to install pip packages and run python files, is the CWD (Current Working Directory) `C:\folder\env\Scripts`? If so, try chaning your CWD to `C:\folder`. I had a similar problem and doing this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to look into a cygwin environment, and look into a chroot or jail environment to run the application without conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use virtualenv-wrapper-win module.
It helps me a lot to manage virtual envs

Answer (score 0):

Life is much easier using Anaconda 3 (it's definitely bloated compared to normal Python though), or use the minimal Miniconda (barebone install, basically just Python + a package manager).  You can download it here: https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html#windows-installers
Then you can make a new virtual environment super easy:

```
conda create -n myenv pip
conda activate
```

If you have multiple environments you do: `conda activate [environment_name]`

Now you're in your new environment with `pip` installed.  And you get drop down menus in the Windows menu to get to your new environment too, so there isn't any searching required.  They just appear.  Now if you want to link Jupyter Notebook or Spyder to the installation, it takes more steps since you need more packages.  I used this guide which basically activates Jupyter first, then Spyder IDE.  https://medium.com/@apremgeorge/using-conda-python-environments-with-spyder-ide-and-jupyter-notebooks-in-windows-4e0a905aaac5

Since you created the environment with pip added you can `pip install` whatever packages you need.  I had to do this recently with OpenBLAS backed NumPy and SciPy (the defaults from pip, not from conda). Now Miniconda is the closest thing to basic Python installation, and comes with some nice tools to make your life easier.  Hopefully this is helpful.